# Former British colonies and cricket

Tags: cricket, history

Some former British colonies, from India to Australia to the nations of the West Indies, have notable cricket teams and a significant number of cricket fans.

However, this is not the same everywhere. While countries such as Canada and Kenya have teams that have played in the World Cup in the past, cricket doesn't seem to excite the same passions that it does elsewhere.

Countries such as Nigeria, Ghana, Malawi and Zambia don't even meet this criterion. The latter two are particularly striking outliers given their proximity to Zimbabwe and South Africa.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Another good example is the USA. It's a major former British colony, and cricket is nearly unheard-of there outside of immigrant communities from *other* former British colonies.

Comment: Cricket is quite an expensive sport to stage - not necessarily in direct cash terms - but in the amount of time that needs to be devoted to the playing of a match. It could be that in countries like Nigeria etc that potential amateurs find it difficult to get enough time off work for an earnest pursual of the sport.  It is hard enough in the UK!

Answer (score 0):

[India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cricket_in_India_to_1918), Australia, and the West Indies had a long history of British colonial rule and exposure to cricket, other nations in Africa, like Nigeria, Ghana, Malawi, and Zambia, had different colonial influences or were not as heavily influenced by British culture.
The development and popularization of cricket require adequate infrastructure, facilities, and resources. In some countries, the lack of proper cricket grounds, training facilities, coaching programs, and funding for the sport can hinder its growth. In those countries, other sports have gained a strong foothold and established themselves as the primary focus of sporting interest. For example, in [Nigeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigeria_national_football_team), football is the most popular sport and has a massive following. The presence of other highly popular sports can divert attention and resources away from cricket. Also the visibility and media coverage of cricket play a significant role in generating interest and excitement among the masses.

Comment: Please refer this link [How cricket became India's passion](https://www.hindustantimes.com/75th-independence-day/cricket/how-cricket-became-india-passion)